# css align header links in middle

Tags: html, css

I've managed to put the `inputs` in the middle of the screen, as you can view here http://jsfiddle.net/xnARk/

**HTML**

```
<table class='header'>
   <tr>
     <td></td>    
     <td style='vertical-align: middle; text-align: center'>
       <table data-role='none' style='width: 50%; margin: auto; border-spacing: 0;' cellspacing='0'>
          <tr>
            <td>
                <input type='text'/>
            </td>
              <td style='width: 35%'>
                   <input type='text'/>
               </td>
          </tr>
     </td>
    </tr>     
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table.header{
    width: 100%; 
        margin: 0; 
        height: 85px;
    background: #D9D9D9
}
```

But, I would also like to put header links beneeth the `inputs`, in center. How can I accomplish that?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to supply more detail e.g. a mock-up of how you want it to look would help. Also, you should list your code in your question, in case, for instance, jsfiddle goes down.

Comment: @agbb why shouldn't I use tables?

Comment: @Danko see my answer below.

Comment: @user3243925 you SHOULD use table for tabular content. But to markup your layout you SHOULD be semantic. it's a more readable markup too, if you use the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you need to use tables, and I am not sure if I understand your questions right, but is this what you're looking for?

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/micahSan/eB4rK/

Basically, this is what I've done:

```
<div id="container">
  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text"/>
      </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <a href="#">Testing</a>
        <a href="#">Longer link goes here</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And your css:

```
#container {
text-align:center; 
vertical-align:middle;
background-color: #cccccc;
}

#myTable {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/xnARk/1/

added:  `<br>here?` under inputs

Comment: Yes and no. http://jsfiddle.net/xnARk/2/
I don't want it to create a second line..I want it to continue on the same one.